# variables not parsed in for loop

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch file code:

```
set run=C:\run.exe
set xml=C:\input.xml

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /R %1 %%i in (*.bin) DO (
    set a=%%i
    set b=!a:foo=bar!
    echo !a!
    echo !b!
    %run% -i %xml% -j !a! -k !b!
)
```

The problem is that, although display message from `echo !a!` and `echo !b!` were correct, `!a!` and `!b!` as the arguments of run.exe were not parsed in the last sentence, which was displayed in the command window as

```
C:\run.exe -i C:\input.xml -j !a! -k !b!
```

Anyone has ideas why they're parsed in echo but not in the last sentence?

Comment: What do you mean by "was displayed as"? I suspect you mean the batch file displays itself as it runs because you don't have `echo off`. In that case, the line will be displayed before the variables get expanded when you use "!" (due to it being _delayed_ expansion).

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou yes, you're right. It's displayed in the command window. Then how can I call run.exe with correct arguments?

Comment: You already are running it with correct arguments.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou but run.exe was not running; it said "The system cannot find the path specified."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment: "The system cannot find the path specified."

I would recommend that you quote your values as I suspect `!a!` and/or `!b!` may have spaces in them:

```
"%run%" -i "%xml%" -j "!a!" -k "!b!"
```

What you are seeing in the command window:

> `C:\run.exe -i C:\input.xml -j !a! -k !b!`

Is likely the initial parsing of the line *before* the delayed expansion has been applied. I suspect if you add `@ECHO OFF` to the very top of your script, you will not see this.

Comment: Add `ECHO` in front of the "run" line and post what is output.

Comment: your suggestion is very helpful; it seems run.exe is called with correct arguments, but it's still not running, and no error is prompted :(

Comment: I found the problem; the path of run.exe was not right. Thanks guys!